# How to fix "doc.exists" error in firestore even though doc exists in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

On clicking button doc.exists prints false even though the doc exists in firestore

```
document.getElementById('q48submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
var question1 = document.getElementById('Q48');
const docRef2 = firestore.doc("CorrectResponses/" + question1.innerText);

var correctResponse;
docRef2.get().then(function(doc){
    if (doc && doc.exists){
        const response1 = doc.data();
        correctResponse = response1.CorrectResponse;
    }
})
});
```

I am a newbie with firebase and expected firebase to return the data in doc variable but it returned false even though the document exists in firestore.

Comment: What happens if you hard code the path of the document instead of using `question1.innerText`?  Is `question1.innerText` exactly what you think it is?

Comment: Also, what kinds of rules do you have in effect?

Comment: The rules of firestore are in public mode and read, write access is given to all

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure question.innerText is fine

Comment: Are you getting `doc` at all or is just `exists` false?

Comment: Yes I am getting doc as following
    t {_firestore: t, _key: t, _document: null, _fromCache: false, _hasPendingWrites: false}
exists: false
id: "The IOT is not a mechanism of"
metadata: t
ref: t
_document: null
_firestore: t {_queue: t, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: {…}, _databaseId: t, _dataConverter: t, …}
_fromCache: false
_hasPendingWrites: false
_key: t {path: e}
    __proto__: Object

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you've connected to the right firebase project? What version of the client SDK are you using and what's your platform?

Comment: Are you "pretty sure" `question1.innerText` is correct?  Or are you absolutely sure, because you logged it or otherwise saw its value in a debugger?  From your dump of the snapshot, I'd say that it's not what you think it is.  Notice "The IOT is not a mechanism...".